# Add-migration and enable-migration are not recognized

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to enable-migrations and add-migration in the project but getting error.
Anyone faced same issue please share your experience.
Visual Studio 2013
Entity Framework 6.4.4

Error:

PM> Add-Migration 'Intialize Database'
Add-Migration : The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- Add-Migration 'Intialize Database'
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-Migration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Hi, has the question been updated recently?  Did Ibrahim Timimi's response help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2022 when developing a .NET CORE 7 application.

1. Added the NuGet package: `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Tools` to my solution. I then restarted Visual Studio 2022.
2. I opened the Package Manager Console and entered the following command:

```
      Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

3. This returned the following error:

```
Add-Migration : The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,...
```

4. I resolved this issue by adding `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Design` package to the solution. This adds a `Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Design` under the root of Packages.

- Note there are now two instances of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`  package in the solution.

The first is a child of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` that was installed by NuGet when `Tools` was installed.

The second instance of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` is installed at the root of Packages.

After installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`, the `Add-Migration` command is recognized.

This creates two instances of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` in the solution. This is probably not the intent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` nuget to access EF Core tools such `Add-Migration`:

Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

.NET CLI command:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Comment: Has EntityFrameworkCore.Tools superseded the tools that worked with EntityFramework 6.4.4 (as highlighted in the question) then? My understanding was these tools are installed with Visual Studio now, as a component?